# ASP.NET Core Accessing Folders Outside Inetpub

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

I have a ASP.NET Core Web app, the issue I'm experiencing when I deployed on the test server is accessing two folders outside of Inetpub: 
C:\Directory\ineedthisone and C:\Directory\ineedthisonetoo. I get Access to path C:\Directory\ineedthisone is denied. I've tried giving permissions to the folder but i still get the same response. Am i missing something?

Comment: What permission did you give to what identity? Is it the identity that the application pool is running as?

Comment: This is prevented because it's usually a bad idea (what if 2 apps used the same folder?).  Why do you want to do it?

Comment: There's not enough info here to help you. Adding permissions is the solution. You just need to ensure that you're giving the permissions to the right identity, namely the one the actual App Pool is running under.

Comment: @Neil, no other app will use the two folders but this. The app is to mange powershell scripts for printer installs as my company uses powershell to automate installation of network printers.

Comment: Why can't these scripts be in a folder under where your code is deployed?

Comment: @Crowcoder The app pool is currently running under an AD user account, and that AD account has permission to the said folders. I do have two backed classes used to access the contents of these would you like to provide one of those classes?

Comment: @Neil I'm not sure about moving them, (i am just an intern), to me would make more sense to have them under wwwroot